# How to add JS script to a page using webpack to be environment dependant

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have plain HTML error pages to which I have to add scripts. One script only for production and one only for development env. Because the back-end is in .Net the best solution to do that would be through webpacks as it's possible to get the environment through that.

Could someone please explain how I can in webpack make it that in prod is one script but in dev env. another? How should these scripts be added to the page and in webpacks.

I do have webpack.dev.js and webpack.prod.js split.

Answer (score 0):

You can create one common config(*`webpack.common.js`*) for development and production  and two separated configs for production(*`webpack.prod.js`*) and development(*`webpack.dev.js`*). Then create tow separated entry `.js` files one for development(*`development.js`*) and one for production(*`index.js`*). Then define entry point as *`development.js`* for *`webpack.dev.js`* and *`index.js`* for *`webpack.prod.js`*. Then in your *`package.json`* you can give different configs for different commands, for build *`webpack.prod.js` and for serve *`webpack.dev.js`*. To merge *`webpack.common.js`* with your production and development config you can use [**`webpack-merge`**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-merge) package.

**Example:**

***Project structure***

```
test/
├── node_modules/
├── development.js
├── index.html
├── index.js
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
├── webpack.common.js
├── webpack.dev.js
└── webpack.prod.js
```

***`package.json`***

```json
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "webpack serve --open --config webpack.dev.js",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.prod.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
    "webpack": "^5.15.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.7.3"
  }
}
```

***`webpack.common.js`***

```js
const path = require('path');
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        }),
    ],
    output: {
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js'],
    },
}
```

***`webpack.dev.js`***

```js
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: './development.js',
    devServer: {
        contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
});
```

***`webpack.prod.js`***

```js
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './index.js'
});
```